# problem with \def\uppercase{} in thesis document

Tags: capitalization

I am writing my thesis and facing the following problem.

When I remove `\def\uppercase{}` (see in the following file after `\begin{document}`. The title of my all chapters, Title "Table of contents", Title "Reference" in the thesis are converted to **CAPITAL** (e.g., REFERENCES instead of References, INTRODUCTION instead of Introduction).

[ed: This question is a follow-up to [listing package error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141293/listing-package-error), where removing `\def\uppercase{}` was the proposed solution.]

How can I fix this issue?

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{Classes/aesm_edspia}

\begin{document}
\def\uppercase{} 

\renewcommand\figurename{\small\textbf{Figure}} 
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\makethese 
\onehalfspacing
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-5}


\frontmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Acknowledgments}

\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}



\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Table of Contents}

\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}
\renewcommand\bibname{Bibliography}
\renewcommand\indexname{Index}
\renewcommand\figurename{Figure}
\renewcommand\tablename{Table}
\renewcommand\partname{Part}
\renewcommand\chaptername{Chapter}
\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}



\input{Abstract/Abstract}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\include{Abstract/LongAbstract}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\include{Abstract/remerciement}

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{List of Figures}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\listoffigures
\listoftables 
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}    

\mainmatter    
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Introduction}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 

\include{Introduction/introduction}
...

\onehalfspacing

\end{document}
```

Comment: What would you like it to look like?  That is, what is the problem with leaving `\def\uppercase{}` intact?

Comment: Thanks @StevenB.Segletes for your reply. I had a listing package problem previously. The solution was suggested by our community to remove `\def\uppercase{}'. Please see previously asked question  for detail [link] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141293/listing-package-error) . But, when I removed `\def\uppercase{}', I faced the above mentioned CAPITAL problem.

Comment: In my ignorance I comment: Shouldn't all definitions be on the preamble of the file?

Comment: `\def\uppercase{}` is a big mistake and should not appear in any document.

Comment: @egreg, I may agree with you that `\def\uppercase{}` should not be appear in the thesis. But, the removal of this line cause the above metioned capital problem.

Comment: @PankeshPatel I can't tell more; please, make an example that shows the problem (without `\include`)

Answer (score 1):

In aesm_despia your have the following line 117:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
```

If you really need this class, but with modified appearance of the titles, please add (early) in your main file the following line

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\chaptername~\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
```

Comment: This solution is not working  in my case.